# Docker para Stability-AI/generative-models (IA generacion de imagenes)

Tags: docker, manejo-de-memoria, inteligencia-artificial

he estado configurando un docker para esta **IA de generacion de imagenes** . He seguido este readme https://github.com/Stability-AI/generative-models , ya tenia todo listo, todas las dependencias que me pide de python sobre todo.

Me disponia a ejecutar las pruebas:

```
streamlit run scripts/demo/sampling.py --server.port <your_port>
```

Pero me da error, que segun he estado viendo por `htop` es porque la **la memoria se llena**.

Estoy en windows con docker desktop.

esta es la interfaz que puedes abrir en el host que te sale que ha desplegado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando empieza a trabajar , van saliendo unos logs de `warnings` por versiones pero que no pasa nada, he mirado por internet que solo es algo informativo.

Pero he hecho varias pruebas y siempre acaban en este error, despues de los warnings:

```
BasicTransformerBlock is using checkpointing
Initialized embedder #0: FrozenCLIPEmbedder with 123060480 params. Trainable: False
Killed
```

Y coincide justo cuando `htop` me muestra que mi memoria RAM de 16 G y la swap de 4G se llena. No se que deberia de hacer para que no se desborde, no dice nada el github sobre esto,  y no se si deberia de configurar algo en la maquina.

Imagen del htop :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si hay alguna manera de limitar la memoria de este proceso, para que no colapse o algo. O que es lo que deberia de hacer para limitarlo si es ese el verdadero problema.